# run lupdate and lrelease command from qt creator in linux

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I want to run lupdate and lrelease command from qtcreator at the time of build.
Is it possible?
If yes then how?

Note: I am using lupdate and lrelease command from linux terminal and its working fine but i want to run these commands from qt creator at the time of build.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using qmake, you should use the `TRANSLATIONS` variable:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#translations

[This](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-programmers.html#specifying-translation-sources-in-qt-project-files) page has some examples:

```
HEADERS         = main-dlg.h \
                  options-dlg.h
SOURCES         = main-dlg.cpp \
                  options-dlg.cpp \
                  main.cpp
FORMS           = search-dlg.ui
TRANSLATIONS    = superapp_dk.ts \
                  superapp_fi.ts \
                  superapp_no.ts \
                  superapp_se.ts
```

The [Hello tr() Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html#creating-a-latin-message-file) explains the process in more detail:

> Note that the file extension is .ts, not .qm. The .ts translation
> source format is designed for use during the application's
> development. Programmers or release managers run the lupdate program
> to generate and update TS files with the source text that is extracted
> from the source code. Translators read and update the TS files using
> Qt Linguist adding and editing their translations.
>
> [...]
>
> Once the translations are complete the lrelease program is used to
> convert the TS files into the QM Qt message file format. The QM format
> is a compact binary format designed to deliver very fast lookup
> performance. Both lupdate and lrelease read all the project's source
> and header files (as specified in the HEADERS and SOURCES lines of the
> project file) and extract the strings that appear in tr() function
> calls.
>
> lupdate is used to create and update the message files (hellotr_la.ts
> in this case) to keep them in sync with the source code. It is safe to
> run lupdate at any time, as lupdate does not remove any information.
> For example, you can put it in the makefile, so the TS files are
> updated whenever the source changes.

Comment: Yes what you suggested above is correct . But this is not what i am expecting. My expectation is to run the command line tool lupdate and lrelease from qt creator and not from linux terminal separately. At the time of build, i want these command line tools to run and generate the .ts and .qm files. Is it possuble??

Comment: It sounds exactly like what you're expecting. Did you try it? I've updated the answer with a quote from another documentation page that goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

in your Qt Creator, go to *Projects > Build Steps*
there you can add two Custom Process Steps with your commands *lupdate* and *lrelease*